# GPOs not applied when moved to OUs containing groups

Tags: windows-10, samba, active-directory

I'm new to AD, and I'm starting with `Samba AD`.

I've created multiple single purpose GPOs, for instance "Shares - Home" which mounts the home share (`\\nas.example.com\home`), another "Shares - Public" which mounts a public share (`\\nas.example.com\Public`) and so on. My users are in the builtin default OU "Users", and when I move these GPOs to the root of my domain, they are applied without any issue. See: [GPO in root of domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgkiC.png)

Now, I try to organise them correctly in a hierarchy using OUs, like so: [Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b840T.png). As I am part of 2 services (`Pédagogie` and `Informatique`), I should apply to my user 2 different sets of GPOs, so I created 2 groups (`Pédagogie` and `Informatique`), my user being a member of both and each group in its corresponding OU. But my user stays in `Users`. You can see here my user being in a group in an OU: [Me and I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkhYe.png).

Then I created more GPOs (more shares, and an admin in the NAS, I have permission to mount them any of them anyway) and carefully placed them in the OUs they are supposed to be part of: [My GPOs in OUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW6TC.png). Problem is, no GPO is applied anymore and `gpresult /R` shows "N/A" as applicable GPOs (not "empty"). If I move the GPOs to the root of the domain, they are applied. If I put them in OUs containing my groups, they are not applied anymore. I even tried to put my user in the root of my OU (ITICPARIS).

I don't even know if I'm doing it right, I'm ruling out a bug with `Samba AD` because we have done the exact same tests with `Windows Server` and the outcome is the same. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... After looking for a while online, I understood that a user can only be part of ONE and ONLY ONE OU at the same time. So my idea to have a user in 2 different groups and only these groups in OU doesn't do anything.

So, from there, the only way to have 2 sets of GPOs applied to a single user, is to create another OU with all the GPOs linked to it. It's redundant but apparently the only way.